# Cannot get consistent element Height inside ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I have an `ion-row` inside an `ion-grid`, and the elements inside the `ion-row` are displayed dynamically following some conditions.

My objective is to retrieve the height of the ion-row once all the conditions are computed and the final view is rendered:

```html
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row #elementContainer>
    <!-- Elements here are displayed dynamically -->
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

```js
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  //...
})
export class ConversationCardPage implements AfterViewInit {

    //...
    @ViewChild("elementContainer", { read: ElementRef }) elementContainer: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.elementContainer && this.elementContainer.nativeElement
           ? this.elementContainer.nativeElement.clientHeight
           : -1)
    }

}
```

Logging this code, I always get the value 0 as the height of the `elementContainer`, but if I change the **ngAfterViewInit** to `ngDoCheck` or `ngAfterContentChecked`, I get the proper height of the element.

As mentioned in the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#docheck), the ngDoCheck has a cost regarding performance, and I would like to stick with the **ngAfterViewInit** since it is supposed to be called once the view is initialized:

> While the ngDoCheck() hook can detect when the hero's name has
>   changed, it has a frightful cost. This hook is called with enormous
>   frequency—after every change detection cycle no matter where the
>   change occurred. It's called over twenty times in this example before
>   the user can do anything.

Comment: Can you give whole code? How does code inside `<ion-row>` renders? When? By inputs? Asynchronous? Because it seems like there is nothing to render during `ngAfterViewInit`.

Try do `console.log(this.elementContainer)` on `ngAfterViewInit` and check if there are any elements inside